# MS-Graph get all messages < 1 hour old

Tags: filter, microsoft-graph-api

Does anyone know if it is possible to configure an MS-Graph query filter so you only receive messages that are less than an hour old (using ReceivedDateTime)?

In all the examples I see, you are forced to enter a static date:

`GET ../me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge 2022-08-08T08:00`

Instead of something like

`GET ../me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge (CurrentDateTime - 1h)`

I need to be able to use a dynamic DateTime because it is being used to trigger a subscription notification.

Comment: Is it the query a part of your application or some script? Could specify the language in which the app is created? Graph API doesn't support getdate,utcnow or similar function. You need to create filter query in your app or script.

Comment: Unfortunately the date is part of a filter that would be added to a mailbox subscription. This subscription is only updated every 3 days but needs to send notifications of new messages that are less than 4 hours old. So yes, something like utcnow() is required.